# Getting all controls of a form in an array using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, controls

How can I get all controls and their values and selected state using JavaScript? It would be good to have an array having all the controls (like select and radio) in an array together with their selected state.

Is that somehow possible?

Thanks!

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Comment: Too big to post, but its all in a form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All the controls of a form are available in the [form.elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-76728479) collection. You can then iterate over the collection and process them however you want.

e.g.

```js
function processForm(form) {
  var control, controls = form.elements;
  for (var i = 0, iLen = controls.length; i < iLen; i++) {
    control = controls[i];

    // Do something with the control
    console.log(control.tagName + ':' + control.name + ' - ' + control.value);
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="form0">
<fieldset><legend>The form</legend>
  <input name="inp0" value="foo"><br>
  <select name="sel0">
    <option value="opt0" selected>opt0
    <option value="opt1">opt1
    <option value="opt2">opt2
  </select><br>
  <input type="button" value="Process form" name="btn0" onclick="
       processForm(this.form);
      ">
  <input type="reset">
</fieldset>
</form>

<input name="outsideForm" form="form0" value="Over the fence">
```

Comment: nips, forgot about form.elements... +1, this is the answer

Comment: Does this work if the form element is outside of the `<form>` tags and is using the HTML5 `form='myform'` attribute?

Comment: @NathanFiscaletti—see edit. I also added a reset button which also works on controls outside the form element but associated using a *form* attribute.

Answer (score 1):

If you do

```
myParentNode.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"], input[type="radio"]');
```

You will get an array of HTMLElements that are `<input>`s with a `type` of `checkbox` or `radio`. You can then access their values with `.value`